# Using Angular built-in i18n with Capacitor

Tags: angular, internationalization, capacitor, angular-i18n

Now we have an application which uses Angular built-in i18n for multi-lingual app and with using Angular built-in i18n there is a separate build for each language. We will use Capacitor as a hybrid mobile solution, but Capacitor copy the application from www directory, in my case there will be folder for each language. So how to handle this in Capacitor, and is it possible to change the URL in runtime when the user changes the language.

Followed these issue ([issue 1](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3905), [issue 2](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/3405), [issue 3](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3912), [issue 4](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4157)) but till now no luck. So if any one struggled to fix this.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, have you found a solution?

Comment: I am also interested in a possible solutions approach